# Server backup to Google Drive

Tags: backup, sync, dropbox, google-drive

I am working on a backup process for a cloud based virtual machine.

I already have a script that will create a tar.gz file, encrypt it with my gpg public key and give it a unique name.

Now I would like to automatically upload it to an online folder. I have both dropbox and google drive and I have enough free storage on either for this task.

I want a solution which will be able to upload one file at a time to a particular folder.

I will need to authorize access to any backup app that runs unattended on my cloud VM and this cloud VM may be hacked so I want to minimal access credentials to my google drive or dropbox files:

- Upload a new file to one particular directory
- Can't read/edit/delete any files anywhere else
- Can't delete or update any files even ones it has previously uploaded

I have looked at rclone (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-sync-your-linux-gui-less-server-to-your-cloud-service-with-rclone/) and grive (https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/sync-documents-with-google-drive-on-ubuntu-linux/) but both seem to want full access to my google drive account.

Does anyone know a way I can leverage my free google/Dropbox storage for this purpose without taking the security risk?

## Update 1

I have investigated Dropbox file requests but it seems this only works using a web interface and there is no API
https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Upload-a-file-via-API-to-a-file-request/td-p/265794

Comment: What OS are you running? Google and Dropbox both have desktop applications that add folders that will automatically sync with there respective cloud.

Comment: I am running ubuntu Server. I have seen both full syncing apps and they can be configured to sync only particular directories to particular directories but they still need access credentials to my whole drive. I want to restrict the access to minimize the damage a hacker could do if they steal credentials from/take control of the server.

Comment: If they "take control of the server" you have bigger issues to worry about.

Comment: It's a small server which houses my personal website and nothing else. I can rebuild it on demand using ansible. I would just need to go into my hosting console blow away the VM and create a new one then deploy the latest backup. If they also got credentials to access/delete all the files I keep in my google drive that would be a far bigger problem!

Comment: Your accounts are exclusively used for this purpose correct?

Comment: No, this is my personal Google Drive account. I considered setting up another google account but I have purchased Google Pixel Phones and Chromebooks and the account has accumulated free google storage. Also even with a separate google account a hacker would be able to delete already uploaded backups.

Comment: Well there's your first problem. Don't use personal. Set up a separate.

Comment: And theres no way (that I know of) to prevent someone with access to the server to get the credentials of the account. If your script has credentials then the credentials are going be visible to anyone who has access to the script.

Comment: What you might be able to do (not sure if possible) is create two google accounts. Create a folder on account A and share it with account B with [upload only permissions](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/4bnaEb9HqZ0). Use the desktop application to upload the files.